# ¿Cómo asignar un valor determinado a un diccionario?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Para una función dada estoy intentando asignar a un diccionario un valor resultante de una operación previa.

Tengo dos parámetros que son magnitudes y lista medidas. Y pese a que consigo asignar las como clave del diccionario no consigo que la media de los valores en una lista sean asignados como valor de las claves del diccionario.

Esto es lo que tengo de momento:

```
def exp (magnitudes,medidas):
"""devuelve para cada magnitud la media de las medidas asociadas a la lista"""

dict_expe = {}
for mag in magnitudes:
    dict_expe[mag] = 0
    for med in medidas:
        suma = 0
    for n in med:
        suma += n
        dict_expe[mag] = suma/len(med)


        return dict_expe

print(exp(['mag1', 'mag2', 'mag3'], [[1,2,3],[3,4],[5]]))
```

El resultado debería ser este:

```
{'mag1': 2.0 , 'mag2': 3.5 , 'mag3': 5.0}
```

Pero lo que estoy consiguiendo es esto:

```
{'mag1': 5.0, 'mag2': 5.0, 'mag3': 5.0}
```

¿A qué se puede estar debiendo?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que para cada elemento de tus magnitudes, estas recorriendo la lista de medidas, y como la lista de medidas siempre termina en 5, por eso estas obteniendo ese valor en cada uno de los valores de tu diccionario.

Una posible solución es recorrer las dos listas al mismo tiempo con `zip`. El código con el mínimo de cambios quedaría algo así:

```
def exp (magnitudes,medidas):
    """devuelve para cada magnitud la media de las medidas asociadas a la lista"""
    dict_expe = {} 
    for mag,med in zip(magnitudes,medidas):
        dict_expe[mag] = 0
        suma = 0
        for n in med:
            suma += n
            dict_expe[mag] = suma/len(med)

    return dict_expe

print(exp(['mag1', 'mag2', 'mag3'], [[1,2,3],[3,4],[5]]))
```

Ahora bien, de acuerdo a tus comentarios, si necesitaras prescindir de `zip()`, puedes hacerlo con ciclos `for` y `range()`:

```
def exp (magnitudes,medidas):
    """devuelve para cada magnitud la media de las medidas asociadas a la lista"""
    dict_expe = {} #crear diccionario vacio
    for i in range(len(magnitudes)):
        dict_expe[magnitudes[i]] = 0 #crear entrada en el diccionario segun cada elemento de magnitudes
        suma = 0 #setear variable suma a 0
        for n in medidas[i]:
            suma += n #sumar todos los numeros por medida
            dict_expe[magnitudes[i]] = suma/len(medidas[i]) #obtener y asignar media en el diccionario

    return dict_expe

print(exp(['mag1', 'mag2', 'mag3'], [[1,2,3],[3,4],[5]]))
```

Comment: Si quisieramos evitar zip() por la futura limitacion de la longitud de las listas, se podria resolver con bulces for?

Comment: @SteveJade Si, por supuesto. En vez de usar las propiedades iterables de las listas, podrias usar range() y acceder a las listas por indices. Pero si van a variar en longitud, como sabrias que medida corresponde a cual longitud?

Comment: Como se podría con un bulce? SI fueran de distinta longitud a las magnitudes se les asignaria un valor nulo. Pero lo que no comprendo es como emplear un bucles for en este caso

Comment: @SteveJade he editado mi respuesta para responderte.

Comment: Muchas gracias, te importaria comentar el codigo ligeramente? Sobre todo las sentencias dentro de los bucles